# what happens in MySQL when multiple tables are used

Tags: mysql, sql

What exactly happens when i write a query like

`Select * from table1,table2,table3`

Am I performing a natural join,inner join or outer join, is it necessary to have primary key- foreign key relations among the tables

Comment: You are performing a cross join. A table without a PRIMARY KEY isn't really a table.

Comment: Like @Strawberry - you're performing a cross join and you're getting a Cartesian Product of your tables. It's necessary to have knowledge about what steps you need to take to reach your goal. So no, you don't have to have any keys. But you might want to. You might want to have FK relations. It all depends on what you're doing and what's the optimal approach. Therefore - knowledge = power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comment, the resulting output is a cartesian product of the three tables. What that means is, you get all possible combinations of the records in the tables. This is also called a CROSS JOIN, since you are not matching any columns on either tables.

So for example, if your table1 contains 5 records ("A", "B", "C", "D" and "E"), your table2 contains 3 records ("1", "2", "3") and your table3 contains 3 records ("x", "y", "z"), your resulting table will contain 5 * 3 * 3 = 45 records:

```
"A", "1", "x"
"A", "1", "y"
"A", "1", "z"
"A", "2", "x"
...
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to bind the primary- and foreign-keys to each other.

But your query selects **all** the data from table1, then selects *so much times* the data from table2 *as the table1 has rows*, and so on.

Following an example:

- You have table1 with 200 rows
- You have table2 with 300 rows

You do `SELECT * FROM table1,table2`. The result would be (200*300=)**60000** rows. If you do this by accident it could block your software for a couple of minutes because it's busy selecting all those rows.